# How can I remove a line from java source code(from file) that has only a opening or closing bracket in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am doing some analysis on java source code and I want to get rid of lines that contain only an opening `{` or closing bracket`}`. And write it back to the same file. How can I achieve this? The code below only checks if the first character is a bracket, this might erase the next content after the bracket, which is something I do not want.

```
with open("source_code.txt", 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if not line[0].lstrip() == "{" or not line[0].lstrip() == "}":
      # Write it back to the same file i.e. source_code.txt
```

INPUT:

```
/**
     * Copy all mappings from given map if they pass validation.
     * If a single value fails validation, none of the others will be committed either.
     *
     * @param map map of keys and values
     * @throws ValidationException if an entry in <tt>map</tt> fails validation
     */
    public void putAll(Map<K, V> map)
    throws ValidationException
    {
        for (K key: map.keySet()) {
            if (mValidators.containsKey(key)) {
                for (Validator validator : mValidators.get(key)) {
                    if (!validator.validate(map.get(key))) {      
                       throw new ValidationException(validator.message());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        mData.putAll(map);
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
/**
     * Copy all mappings from given map if they pass validation.
     * If a single value fails validation, none of the others will be committed either.
     *
     * @param map map of keys and values
     * @throws ValidationException if an entry in <tt>map</tt> fails validation
     */
    public void putAll(Map<K, V> map)
    throws ValidationException
        for (K key: map.keySet()) {
            if (mValidators.containsKey(key)) {
                for (Validator validator : mValidators.get(key)) {
                    if (!validator.validate(map.get(key))) {
                       throw new ValidationException(validator.message());
        mData.putAll(map);
```

Comment: How about checking the length of `line` along with this?

Comment: see answer, if you want to also delete the trailing `{` or some other characters just update your question and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `splitlines()` to split the text file to rows and use `startswith()` to check if a string starts with a substring.

```py
with open("source_code.txt", 'r') as f:
    rows = f.read().splitlines()

output = []

for row in rows:
    if not (row.lstrip().startswith("{") or row.lstrip().startswith("}")):
        output.append(row)

with open("source_code.txt", 'w') as f:
    for row in output:
        f.write(row + '\n')
```

This is the result

```
/**
     * Copy all mappings from given map if they pass validation.
     * If a single value fails validation, none of the others will be committed either.
     *
     * @param map map of keys and values
     * @throws ValidationException if an entry in <tt>map</tt> fails validation
     */
    public void putAll(Map<K, V> map)
    throws ValidationException
        for (K key: map.keySet()) {
            if (mValidators.containsKey(key)) {
                for (Validator validator : mValidators.get(key)) {
                    if (!validator.validate(map.get(key))) {      
                       throw new ValidationException(validator.message());

        mData.putAll(map);
```